# Open autossh port for public access

Tags: ssh, debian, proxy, nat, local

I want to access a Raspberry Pi Zero W on the local network via [NAT traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal). I was following [this tutorial (in Chinese)](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/34908698), but am having the issue described below.

The idea is to forward the SSH port on the local Raspberry Pi to remote machine with a public IP, and then access the Pi from there. For security reasons, I have replaced the real values with `nalzok@remote-ip`.

#### On Raspberry Pi (access from the local network)

```
pi@nalzoks-pi:~ $ autossh -M 30000 -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=false" -o "ServerAliveInterval 10" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -NR 20000:localhost:22 nalzok@remote-ip
```

#### On remote server

I have no issue logging to the Pi from the remote server

```
nalzok@iZuf68c45z6sk19lln4zvsZ:~$ ssh -p20000 pi@localhost
Linux nalzoks-pi 4.19.66+ #1253 Thu Aug 15 11:37:30 BST 2019 armv6l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Sun Sep  8 10:12:30 2019 from ::1
pi@nalzoks-pi:~ $
```

#### On my computer (outside of the local network)

However, I cannot access it directly from my computer.

```
$ ssh -p20000 pi@remote-ip
ssh: connect to host remote-ip port 20000: Connection refused
```

#### On remote server

I'm pretty sure the firewall is opened for both port 20000 and 30000 on the remote server. When trying to troubleshot myself, I realized that these ports are only available for local access.

```
nalzok@iZuf68c45z6sk19lln4zvsZ:~$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
[sudo] password for nalzok:
sshd        601    root    3u  IPv4  13223      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      12503    root    8u  IPv4 879255      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:1234 (LISTEN)
sshd      13026  nalzok    9u  IPv4 885817      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:30000 (LISTEN)
sshd      13026  nalzok   10u  IPv4 885818      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:20000 (LISTEN)
```

How do I open the port 20000 for public access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This remote forwarding behavior is explicitly documented in the [the SSH man page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#R_5):

> By default, TCP listening sockets on the server will be bound to the
>   loopback interface only. This may be overridden by specifying a
>   bind_address. An empty bind_address, or the address ‘*’, indicates
>   that the remote socket should listen on all interfaces. Specifying a
>   remote bind_address will only succeed if the server's GatewayPorts
>   option is enabled (see sshd_config(5)).

If the [`GatewayPorts` option](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config.5#GatewayPorts) is enabled on the server, you'd specify the remote forward like this to take advantage of it:

```
-R *:20000:localhost:22
```